# Wordpress: Issues trying to display all comments in one page

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to modify my wordpress theme (inove) to display all comments in the same page instead of 50 comments per page.

I opened the comments.php file, commented out calls to paginate_comments_links() and and set the wp_list_comments() as follows:

```
wp_list_comments('type=comment&callback=custom_comments&per_page=100&page=1');
```

The problem is, whenever someone posts a comments, the comment form appends '/comment-page-2/' to the URL after submitting the comment, even though I've specified that all comments to be displayed on the same page.

Any idea what I could be missing?

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily turn off comment pagination in your WordPress settings. Go to Settings > Discussion, then uncheck `Break comments into pages with...`

If the theme is well written, it should obey your settings correctly and display comments accordingly (and so there should be no need to edit the theme files).

Comment: it's THAT easy? I've been messing around with it for two months now! teaches me a lesson to not wear the developer hat immediately next time, and try to find a simpler solution first. Thank you very much TheDeadMedic. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach (get_comments() as $comment): ?>
    <div>
      <?php echo $comment->comment_author; ?>
      <?php echo $comment->comment_content; ?>"
   </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

For pagination, you can use the offset and number parameters of the get_comments() arguments:

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'number'=>20,
        'offset'=>0,
        'status'=>'approve',
    );
    foreach (get_comments($args) as $comment) {
        // ...
    }
?>
```